# What CSS do I need for a fixed right panel?

Tags: css

I would like a two-column web page with the right panel fixed-width and the left panel taking up the remaining space. The right panel should not scroll, but the left panel should. The scroll bar must be in between the left and right columns (in other words, the left `div` needs its own scroll bar rather than the whole page scrolling).

I currently have the HTML:

```
<div id="l"><!-- Lots of text so it will scroll --></div>
<div id="r">Right panel</div>
```

and CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#l {
  padding: 10px 360px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #808080;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#r {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-left: 1px solid #353535;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

At the moment, the scroll bar appears on the right of the whole page, rather than just the left `div` scrolling. Please help! (You can play with [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DPZha/).)

Comment: Did you give it a try in your actual application? If so then was the scroll bar there for the entire page as well?

Comment: @ladiesMan217 The results are the same in my actual app (tested in IE9, Chrome).

Comment: hmm when I remove the right panel I see a disabled scrollbar on your left panel somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `height` for `#main` wrapper and set `overflow: hidden;` :
http://jsfiddle.net/DPZha/8/

Answer (score 0):

The code you have atm is 100% correct. Your right panel is fixed, using the scrollbar will only scroll the left panel and leave one the right unharmed.

If the `body`-scrollbar bothers you, give your `html`,`body`and left panel 100% height and make it scroll on overflow. I updated your [example-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/DPZha/9/) to reflect that. Note, that you need to set the width of both, `#r` and `#l` accordingly, so the fixed `#r` won't overlap the left column.

Comment: +1 This is great, except I need the width of the left panel to be "whatever space is left", rather than a fixed width. Is this possible in CSS? (Yes I could do a JS hack but I'd rather not.)

Comment: I think this won't be possible with vanilla CSS. Since `position:fixed` removes the right column from the normal document flow, you don't know, how much space you have left for the left column.

Comment: Btw, your example fiddle had the same problem. Change one of your "X" to some lengthy word and see how it gets clipped.